# setValue of JSON results (lat/lon coordinates as Double) to CoreData in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

Im very new with iOS/xCode development using Swift. I'm attempting to do the following:

Query a JSON result and save the values to CoreData that will include a lat/lon coordinate that needs to be saved as a Doubles.  Here is my current snippet that will not allow me to save the lat/lon as Double even when the item/value is set to NSNumber:

CoreData settings:

```
Entity Attributes and type:
apCode: String
apId: String
apLat: Double
apLon: Double
apName: String
apUpdate: Date
```

func snippet:

```
let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

           var items = [[String:AnyObject]()]
           var item:AnyObject

            for var i = 0; i < jsonResult[“jsonAirports"]!.count; i++ {

                items.append([String:AnyObject]())

                item = jsonResult[“jsonAirports"]![i] as NSDictionary 

                items[i]["AIRPORT"] = item["AIRPORT"] as? String

                items[i]["APCODE"] = item["APCODE"] as? String

                items[i]["APID"] = item["APID"] as? String

                items[i]["LAT"] = item["LAT"] as? NSNumber

                items[i]["LON"] = item["LON"] as? NSNumber

                items[i]["IMG"] = item["IMG"] as? String

                items[i]["UDATE"] = item["UDATE"] as? NSDate


                //Save to CoreData
                var addAirportItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Airports", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["AIRPORT"], forKey: "apName")                    

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["APCODE"], forKey: "apCode")

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["APID"], forKey: "apID")

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["LAT"], forKey: "apLat")

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["LON"], forKey: "apLon")

                addAirportItem.setValue(items[i]["IMG"], forKey: "apImg")

                addAirportItem.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "apUpdate")

                context.save(nil)

            }
```

My goal is to compare user's current location using CoreLocation and fetch the corresponding item from CoreData using the saved lat/lon coordinates.

How do I set the JSON results for lat/lon coordinates to be saved as Doubles in CoreData?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Octavious

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: Sorry. It was implied at the Title, but I edited and added the question: How do I set the JSON results for lat/lon coordinates to be saved as Doubles in CoreData?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it looks like the issue is a datatype mismatch between the properties described in your CoreData model and the type of the value you are trying to set on the properties.

If your CoreData model, `apLat` and `apLon` are both `String`, but you are trying to set them with `NSNumber` in your snippet. If you change the type to Double in your model, I think your snippet would work.

Comment: Sorry about that.  The data type in the model for apLat and apLon is already set to Double (posted incorrectly above). With the current snippet I included, when I run the func, the CoreData results in nil for those two values.